# Pandas Function getting error comparing floating number and integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am using Pandas to analyze a dataset which includes a column named "Age on Intake" (floating numbers). I had been trying to further categorize the data into a few small age buckets using the function I wrote. However, I keep getting the error **"*'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'*"**. How could I fix this please?

**My function:**

```
def convert_age(num):
    
    if num <=7:
        return "0-7 days"
    elif num <= 21:
        return "1-3 weeks"
    elif num <= 42:
        return "3-6 weeks"
    elif num <= 84:
        return "7-12 weeks"
    elif num <= 168:
        return "12 weeks - 6 months"
    elif num <= 365:
        return "6-12 months"
    elif num <= 730:
        return "1-2 years"
    elif num <= 1095:
        return "2-3 years"
    else:
        return "3+ years"
   
df['Age on Intake'] = df['Age on Intake'].apply(convert_age)
```

**The df['Age on Intake'] column includes floating numbers:**

```
0          95.0
1        1096.0
2         111.0
3         111.0
4         397.0
          ...  
21474       NaN
21475       NaN
21476     365.0
21477     699.0
21478      61.0
Name: Age on Intake, Length: 21479, dtype: float64
```

**Error Message I get:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-ca12621d6b19> in <module>
     22         return "3+ years"
     23 
---> 24 df['Age on Intake'] = df['Age on Intake'].apply(convert_age)
     25 
     26 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-31-ca12621d6b19> in convert_age(num)
      3 def convert_age(num):
      4 
----> 5     if num <=7:
      6         return "0-7 days"
      7     elif num <= 21:

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Please always post the data and code as code and not as screenshots. Also include a sample of your data and the full error traceback.

Comment: Thank you @not_speshal for the tips. My first time posting and just edited

Comment: Hmm it really should work given that your Series shows `dtype: float64`. There are better ways to categorize this data though, using `pd.cut`. Are you sure you didn't already `.apply(convert_age)` to that column and which would make it string values and then you accidentally try to call the function again

Comment: I suggest you debug this by putting a try except statement in the function and print the value of num if there is an error. You can then find the value it is failing on.

Comment: With `float` values, your code works perfectly fine for me. Can you try running `df['Age on Intake'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age on Intake'])` and see if that also raises errors?

Comment: @ALollz Wow thank you! Indeed it was because I called the function again after I modified the code to add another line of 'elif' statement.(A nooby's struggle). I really appreciate everyone's input!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `num` argument in the `convert_age` receives a string instead of an int value. Try either converting it into an int, or ignore incoming values other than ints.
Consider adding something like this.

```
try:
    converted_num = int(num)  # Trying to convert to int.
    # your code goes here
except ValueError:
    # We got an error while converting.
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering to the question (the issue is indeed a type problem that can be solved with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)), but you could advantageously replace your unfriendly function with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ages = {0: '0-7 days',
        7: '1-3 weeks',
        21: '3-6 weeks',
        42: '7-12 weeks',
        84: '12 weeks - 6 months',
        168: '6-12 months',
        365: '1-2 years',
        730: '2-3 years',
        1095: '3+ years'}

pd.cut(df['Age on Intake'].astype(float),
       bins=list(ages.keys())+[np.inf],
       labels=ages.values(),
      )
```

Comment: Very helpful! Did not know about this before. Thank you